# How to disable autostart all tasks on airflow restart?

Tags: celery, airflow

We have a problem. When we restart airflow - all our tasks start at this time an heavy load our servers. How to we can prevent start all tasks on airflow restart?

Example of task:

```
    default_args = {
     'owner': 'airflow',
     'depends_on_past': False,
     'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 2),
     'email': ['test@test.com'],
     'email_on_failure': True,
     'email_on_retry': True,
     'retries': 1,
     'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
     'catchup': False

 }

 dag = DAG(
     'start_data_collect', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))

 t1 = BashOperator(
     task_id='print_date',
     bash_command='date',
     dag=dag)
```

Comment: Did you change anything in airflow.cfg for `max_threads`? Or do you use Celery or the like?

Comment: We use Celery with default settings.

Comment: Then you might want to change the setting `celeryd_concurrency`.

Answer (score 0):

If your servers are getting a heavy load it's because its easy for your workers to all connect and query/use them. I recommend that next time, before you restart Airflow, you look at all the dags using connections to servers that might get overloaded, and you configure their tasks to each use a pool, probably one per server or connection. You'll also need to create the pool in the UI with slots. But v1.9 and later have a patch that auto creates pools with 0 slots, so you can use the UI to go in and add a few slots to each of those. This way, even if the scheduler can schedule many available tasks, it will not schedule more the the number of tasks can fit in the slots.

Answer (score 0):

If you toggle the status to "OFF" in the UI, it should stop your DAG. If you want new DAGs to be disabled by default, you can update set dags_are_paused_at_creation = True under [core] in your airflow config.